# Apart from Owin, does anything else exist for authentication work as middle ware?

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, owin, adal

I have a problem with Owin. It's old and not much appreciated anymore. Moreover, it's really not workable in ISS when combined with .NET Remoting.

I really need to know if any other security middle layer exists which can be plugged and can be used to read Claims and tokens sent to the Web server from the client side. ( Probably access_token accessed using adal.net )

For example in Startup, can anything else be used?

I really don't want to use OWIN.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution other than using OWIN, apart from maybe creating custom middleware.

Why do you not want to use it? Without OWIN you may be able to achieve what you want through System.Web or with the HTTP abstractions that come with ASP.NET 5. But then you'll need to support different runtimes and it will be a lot more complex.

OWIN is supported by all the ASP.NET worlds so it's really the best and only option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1